# How to reference an aliased column in an implicit cursor loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following Oracle PL/SQL implicit cursor loop:

```
FOR c IN
(
  SELECT 1 AS "mycol",column2 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS "mycol",column2 FROM DUAL
)
LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c.mycol);
END LOOP;
```

When I run I get the error message

> PLS-00302; component 'mycol' must be declared.

How can I reach this explicitly inserted column 'mycol' in my implicit cursor loop?

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c."mycol");`

Comment: By default all names on oracle in upper case. `c.mycol` is equivalent of `c."MYCOL"` not a `"mycol"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "How can I reach this explicitly inserted column 'mycol' in implicit cursor loop?"

It's not `mycol` it's `"mycol"`. You labeled it with double-quotes which makes it case-sensitive. So either change your reference ...

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c."mycol");
```

... or, better, change the column alias:

```
SELECT 1 AS mycol,  column2 FROM DUAL
```

Double-quoted identifiers are tricksy: if we use them when naming objects we have to be careful to use double-quotes and the exact same case thereafter. The one except is when the identifier is all in upper-case. Then double-quotes are optional. `"MYCOL"` and `MYCOL` are equivalent, as indeed is `mycol`.

The best thing is to avoid using double-quotes unless you have a pressing reason to do so.

Comment: I would give you +5 if I could for that last sentence alone.  For an amusing read on case sensitivity: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9525305800346887676